# Google form (onEdit)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

It seems that OnEdit only works for spreadsheet?
I have a google form to capture data and sends to user's Calendar. But is there a way to append data if user decides to edit the form submission?

I can't find a trigger for 'edit' of form submission.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the google apps script guides.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#available_types_of_triggers

There you see that the onEdit trigger is only available for Sheets.  However, it seems you could use a  installable trigger that will fire on form submit.